# Passing object through intent from activity to activity

Tags: android-intent

i want to pass a custom class object named "UserItem" from one activity to another. I tried many solutions, but nothing seems to work.

The Class has implemented "Serializable".

Here's the code where i set the item to intent:

```
intent.putExtra("currentItem", item);
```

and the way i'm retrieving it back:

```
UserItem checkItem = (UserItem)intent.getExtras().getSerializable("currentItem");
```

but i'm always getting the error:

```
java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to xxx.xxx.model.entity.UserItem
```

did i forget something?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
//To pass:
 intent.putExtra("Value", obj);

 // To retrieve object in another Activity
 getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Value");
```